# How to subtract Yesterday count by today count group by id in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to subtract the Yesterday Count by today count using startDate and group by id.

[image]

Expected result is

```
id  startDate      count newColumn
xyz Yesterday date  46    40(yesterday-today)
xyz Today     date  6    today-nextday
```

Comment: This should be a static column, not a measure? Why newColumn for today is -40?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
measure= calculate(sum(count), previousday(startdate))
```

Comment: CALCULATE(sum(Sheet3[count]), PREVIOUSDAY(Sheet3[start date].[Date]))


 will give you late date and then create another dax to subtract


Do let me know if it is done or not

Comment: Can you tell another DAX formula pls

Comment: measure= CALCULATE(sum (Sheet3[count])- CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet3[count]),DATEADD(Sheet3[start date],-1,DAY)))


i tried below one that also gives me proper ans